# Нужно ли веб программисту знать Си?

Tags: c

На одном из американских сайтов я прочел статью, в которой говорилось, что даже веб программист должен знать основы языка Си. Аргументировал тем, что при работе с языками высокого уровня программист, иногда не замечает ошибки, которые он бы заметил при работе с языками низкого уровня. Так вот теперь думаю, я php программист, и работал только с ним. PHP был моим первым языком программирования, а информацию черпал из книг. Как думаете прав ли этот программист, стоит ли тратить время на язык Си?

Comment: А сколько там того С, что бы его выучить (другое дело уметь пользоваться).

Уча С, можно узнать о алгоритмах, о использовании памяти, о других базовых вещах. Также, в многих языках используются С подобные конструкции.

Comment: Скажем так - лишним не будет. Но и обойтись без него тоже можно. Что-то вроде "зачем учить матан". С одной стороны, практическое его применение - штука нечастая, а с другой - матан - это прекрасное средство привести мозги в порядок. С Си ситуация похожа (впрочем, наверное, в существенно меньшей степени)

Comment: Чем больше языков вы знаете, тем лучше. C вообще классика, его не знать должно быть стыдно.

Comment: Значит лишним не будет, но и с разными подходами в программировании познакомит. Ведь так!

Comment: в самообразовании не бывает слова "тратить". если вы считаете, что вам не хватает знаний, изучайте. по крайней мере что-нибудь кроме php знать (или хотя быть знакомым) будет полезно в любом случае. а ошибки - их не делает тот, кто ничего не делает.

Comment: Исходить нужно из того, что веб-программист прежде всего - программист. А все программисты, с которыми приходилось общаться (нормальные, а не дети уровня "свой сайт на джумле за полчаса") достаточно свободно владеют минимум 3-4-5 языками, и имеют представление ещё о десятке... И C у всех входит в обязательную программу.

Comment: Думаю, дело в так называемых «дырявых абстракциях» (у Спольского [есть статья на эту тему](http://russian.joelonsoftware.com/Articles/LeakyAbstractions.html)). Если в PHP что-то пойдёт не так из-за несостыковок в низкоуровневых вещах, то знание этих самых низкоуровневых вещей поможет быстро разобраться в проблеме. А изучение Си как раз и затрагивает эти вещи (к примеру, строки, кодировки и работу с памятью).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Я бы поставил вопрос по-другому: "А что я получу в результате, если изучу язык программирования С?". Понимаете, в человеческой сфере деятельности НЕТ ГРАНИЦ. Можно творить и созидать без конца. Что ни день, то новое знание или новая прикольная задача. Будьте хакером! Напомню определение этого слова. Это человек полностью увлеченный компьютером и компьютерными системами. Грубо говоря сказать хакеру : "Вышел новый прикольный язык программирования" и будьте уверены, он хотя бы Hello-world, но напишет! Это в журналах это быдло-мудак, которые ворует деньги и творит пакости, а в жизни это больной на голову до головоломок в сфере ИТ.

Вот когда захотите быть Хакером, каким его понимают FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD, Linux и др. сообщества, тогда Вам не надо будет задавать вопросы подобные Вашему!

Comment: Не хочется даже связываться с линуксоидами не могут рендеринг шрифтов нормально сделать , уже миллион времени прошло.

Comment: и обои скучные

Comment: @vkovalchuk88 ну линуксоиды -- они такие. Но всё-таки, в чём проблема? Какой рендеринг шрифтов они не могут сделать (с учётом того, что xfree -- это не линуксоиды)

@Nofate обои -- да. В 96'м меня плавающие рыбки доставали, всё хотел убрать, да лениво было.

Answer (score 4):

Постоянно, везде говорю и не устаю повторять как заклинание: нормальный прогер неважно кто он, должен знать один из 3-х столпов программирования - C/C++, Java или C#. Это примерно то же самое что и знание основ математики для выпускника школы.

Согласен с определением [@VladD](/users/10105/vladd):

> C вообще классика, его не знать должно быть стыдно

Comment: Может че-то из функциональных в ваш список стоит добавить? Haskell там к примеру, или F#?

Comment: @SoloMio python подойдёт?

@DreamChild ссылки поправьте...

Comment: @SoloMio нет - пока рановато. Пройдет лет 10 тогда может быть.

Comment: как то негоже ставить С и С# как эквиваленты. Я бы разделил эти сполпы иначе

0. С и алгоритмы с структурами данных (возможно, + базовый ассемблер)
1. С++/Java/C#/ObjectiveC/ObjectPascal|Delphi (что то одно, упор на классы)
2. Perl/Python/PHP/Javascript (как минимум что то одно, упор на веб/скриптовость)
3. Haskell/Ocalm/F# (упор на функциональность)

Comment: Я не согласен)) Знания знаниями, но на хлеб тоже нужно зарабатывать. И в данном примере я лучше сделаю упор на js (в моем случае), чем буду изучать один из перечисленных языков в ответе. Да, уже потом, я думаю, когда всё будет комильфо, то определенно стоит взяться за изучение. Но когда оно будет?)...

Comment: Почему-то все забывают про SQL (а это ведь совсем другой подход к программмированию).

Comment: изучив немножко haskell я начал писать совершенно другой (и как мне кажется, более красивый) код на с++ и перл. Попробуйте!

@avp SQL близкий к функциональным языкам. его в группу номер 4.

Comment: >SQL близкий к функциональным языкам

эмм..чем же?

Comment: присмотритесь. select - один с основных операторов выборки данных. у него есть where и group by/having. Это практически эквиваленты filter и fold, которые присутствуют в том или ином виде в любом функциональном языке. Дальше. В функциональных языках принято манипулировать массивами сущностей, не делая явных циклов. При этом часто порядок не имеет значения. В sql аналогично.

Можно ещё много привести примеров.

Думаю, что людям, знакомым с функциональными языками на порядок легче изучить sql, чем тем, кто их не знает.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо, haskell я смотрел, но что-то не потянуло пробовать писать на нем. Наверное, времени для изменения "хода мыслей" не хватило.

--

А по поводу включения SQL в одну группу с haskell, я как-то сомневаюсь, что это правильно.

По сути SQL (вместе с Prolog) это язык исчисления предикатов (точнее SQL это язык реляционного исчисления, которое является частью исчисления предикатов), а гугл на запрос:

    исчисление предикатов +haskell

говорит:

    Нет результатов

(правда, често произнаюсь, я не большой спец в этих теориях).

Comment: @Barmaley ♦

       нет - пока рановато. Пройдет лет 10 тогда может быть.

Приятно общаться с оптимистами.

@DreamChild


       SQL близкий к функциональным языкам
        эмм..чем же?

Наверное принадлежностью к декларативным языкам. Больше вроде нечем.

@avp

       По сути SQL (вместе с Prolog) это язык исчисления предикатов (точнее SQL это язык реляционного исчисления, которое является частью исчисления предикатов), а гугл на запрос:

Насчёт языков логического программирования и haskell см. currry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry_(programming_language)

Answer (score 2):

С/С++ думаю надо ознакомиться с синтаксисом и конструкциями, знать досконально не нужно. Остальные языки типа Java C# совсем не нужны, если вы хорошо знаете PHP/Python/Ruby (Web).

Answer (score 0):

Ну если человек выучил PHP, то выбрал направление Web. Что на Си можно написать сайт? На Си можно написать браузер =)
Ну если и можно что то написать на Си для Web то все равно будешь использовать HTML, JavaScript.
Лучше человеку наверное поучить JavaScript т.к. для Web это ближе.

Для разработки Web приложение требуется связка минимум HTML, JS, PHP.

P.S.
Это лично моё мнение, может я и не прав.

Comment: @FrancNet, тут дело в том, что вкладывать в слово "знать".

--

Если знание синтаксиса и формальных преобразований данных, то это одно, а если понимание как именно в компьютере обрабатываются данные, как они представлены в памяти, чего стоит (в смысле времени выполнения набора машинных команд) та или иная конструкция языка, то это совершенно другое...